# Do Mac OS have ability to delete individual files in the trash can?

Tags: windows, macos, file, operating-system, delete-file

OS handle file deletion I came to know that Mac Os doesn't provide individual file deletion from trash can and can only empty everything why is that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a UX decision. If you're so minded, open the terminal and navigate to `~/.Trash` to `rm` files one by one on the Mac. Apple's version of the trash can metaphor is that you put things in it, then tip it all away. Not that you put things in it, then pick through it deciding which things you really, really don't want. Like a real trash can.

Answer (score 1):

macOS *does* provide individual file deletion from the Trash, it's just a little bit hidden. If you open the trash and secondary-click(*) on an item in it, you'll get a shortcut menu that includes the "Delete Immediately" choice.

*) "Secondary-click" is the macOS equivalent of right-clicking. By default, the right button on a multi-button does a secondary-click, as does holding the Control key while doing a standard click. Other options can be configured in the Mouse and Trackpad preferences in System Preferences. See [Apple support document #HT207700: How to right-click on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207700).